# Не меняется значение EdiText, когда срабатывает условие

Tags: android, kotlin

На экране 5 EdiText (a, b, c, x1, x2. Когда в 3х первых есть какое-то значение, то считается формула и в два других EditText (x1Value, x2Value) должно ставится значение , которое вычислили, но значение в x1Value, x2Value не ставится.
Если смотреть Log.d, то программа зависает именно на том месте, где нужно ставить значение

```
    class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(), TextWatcher {
        var a: Double = 0.0
        var b: Double = 0.0
        var c: Double = 0.0
        var x1: Double = 0.0
        var x2: Double = 0.0
        var flag: Boolean = false


        override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

            aValue.addTextChangedListener(this)    
            bValue.addTextChangedListener(this)    
            cValue.addTextChangedListener(this)    
            x1Value.addTextChangedListener(this)    
            x2Value.addTextChangedListener(this) 

        }


        override fun afterTextChanged(s: Editable?) {
        }

        override fun beforeTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, count: Int, after: Int) {
        }

        override fun onTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, before: Int, count: Int) {


            try {
                a = aValue.text.toString().toDouble()
                b = bValue.text.toString().toDouble()
                c = cValue.text.toString().toDouble()
                x1 = x1Value.text.toString().toDouble()
                x2 = x2Value.text.toString().toDouble()

            } catch (e: Exception) {}



                if (a != 0.0 && b != 0.0 && c != 0.0) {
                    var D = b * b - 4 * a * c

                    var x1_number = ((-1)) * b + Math.sqrt(D) / 2 * a
                    var x2_number = ((-1)) * b - Math.sqrt(D) / 2 * a

                    if (D < 0) {

                        isSol.text = "No real roots"
                    }
                    else{

                            x1Value.setText("$x1_number", TextView.BufferType.EDITABLE)
                            x2Value.setText("$x2_number", TextView.BufferType.EDITABLE)

                        }

                }




        }
    }
}
```

Comment: У тебя последняя "}" ничего не закрывает, мб дело в этом?

Comment: Я с котлином не очень, но разве здесь имя переменной должно быть в кавычках -  ``x1Value.setText("$x1_number", TextView.BufferType.EDITABLE)``? Этож получается просто строка.

Comment: @Keeplod в самом коде все скобки стоят, просто здесь убрал все Log.d, чтобы не захламлять вопрос. Если бы скобок не было, то вообще бы не собрался проект.

Comment: @Эникейщик Да, так можно. Называется строковый шаблон. Т.е. в EditText нужно запихнуть String, тут просто убираю x1_number.toString(), т.е. короче делаю.

Comment: А если попробовать так: `x1Value.text = Editable.Factory.getInstance().newEditable("$x1_number")`?

Comment: @VasilBaymurzin не работает, так же зависает на x1Value.setText

Comment: @GiveMe, если `setText` заменили на `x1Value.text =`, то как может зависать на `setText`? Или не заменили, а просто добавили?

Comment: Проблема в том, что `TextWatcher` срабатывает на каждое изменение текста, в том числе и программное. Вы вводите символ, срабатывает слушатель и изменяет все едиты, на что срабатывают их слушатели снова изменяют и снова срабатывают...........и всё зацикливается

Comment: Если правильно понял, Вам достаточно не ставить `addTextChangedListener` на `x1` и `x2`, чтобы они не изменяли сами себя

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот это удалите, и будет работать

```
x1Value.addTextChangedListener(this)    
x2Value.addTextChangedListener(this)
```

Не надо подписываться на изменения, которые сами и производите. Вот и уходит исполнение в бесконечный цикл.

Comment: Да, выше был комментарий отписаться от этого. Дело в том, что далее нужно будет и в x1Value, x2Value менять значение, чтобы вычислить значение в aValue, bValue, cValue.

Comment: Если хотите в обе стороны вычислять, надо писать логику по динамической подписке\отписке на изменения. Иначе зацикливание обеспечено.

Answer (score 2):

beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) - метод вызывается до изменений, чтобы уведомить нас, что в строке s, начиная с позиции start вот-вот будут заменены count символов, новыми after символами. Изменение текста s в этом методе является ошибкой.

onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) - метод вызывается, чтобы уведомить нас, что в строке s, начиная с позиции start, только что заменены after символов, новыми count символами. Изменение текста s в этом методе является ошибкой.

afterTextChanged(Editable s) - метод вызывается, чтобы уведомить нас, что где-то в строке s, текст был изменен. В этом методе можно вносить изменения в текст s, но будьте осторожны, чтобы не зациклиться, потому что любые изменения в s рекурсивно вызовут этот же метод.

В вашем случае нужно использовать **afterTextWatcher**

Comment: Да, так и поступлю. Далее, буду думать, как менять значение в x1Value, x2Value, чтобы автоматом менялись в aValue, bValue, cValue.